# How to use the checkbox in a table php

Tags: php

Hi I wanted to use a checkbox in a table to update data from my database and also see data from my database, Like i have a field on my database that is called "p_estado" that means status and when the status is at 1 in the database it shows checked and when it's not it doesn't show checked and let me "check" it.

Code:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM pedidos order by p_id desc")

or die(mysqli_error());

echo "{$_SESSION['login_username']}";
echo "<table border='20' cellpadding='20' width=80% height=30px  >";

echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Assunto</th> <th>Portal</th> <th>Destinado</th> <th>Estado</th> </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr>";

echo '<td height="50px" > ' . $row['p_id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td height="50px" >' . $row['p_titulo'] . '</td>';
echo '<td height="50px" >' . $row['p_portal'] . '</td>';
echo '<td height="50px" >' . $row['p_autor'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;</center></td>';
echo '<td><a href="p_editar.php?id=' . $row['p_id'] . '"><center><img src="../imagens/3.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></center></a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="p_delete.php?id=' . $row['p_id'] . '"><center><img src="../imagens/2.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></center></a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="p_viewall.php?id=' . $row['p_id'] . '"><center><img src="../imagens/7.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></center></a></td>';

echo "</tr>";

} 


echo "</table>";
echo "<p><b>Ver Todos</b> | <a href='a_view-paginated.php?page=1'>Ver por Página</a></p>";
?>

</center>
</font>
</body>

</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
include("../login/session.php");
        if(!empty($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']) 
     && file_exists($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
    $imgData= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
}
        $imageProperties = getimageSize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
        $portal = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field1']);
        $datacri = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field2']);
        $datacri = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datacri)));
        $datapub = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field3']);
        $datapub = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $datapub)));
        $titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field4']);
        $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field5']);
        $hashtags = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field6']);
        $pedido = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field7']);
        $autor = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['field8']);
if (!$portal) { 
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Preencha todos os campos "); </script>';
header('Refresh: 0; URL=../forms/p_criar.php');
mysqli_close($link);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos (p_id, p_portal, p_datacri, p_datapub, p_titulo, p_keywords, p_hashtags, p_imageType, p_imageData, p_pedido, p_autor,p_nomeuti)
        VALUES('Null', '$portal', '$datacri', '$datapub', '$titulo', '$keyword', '$hashtags', '{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '$pedido', '$autor', '{$_SESSION['login_username']}')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Portal Criado"); </script>';
    header('Refresh: 0; URL=../forms/p_criar.php');
    } else{
    header('Refresh: 0; URL=../forms/p_criar.php');
    echo "ERRO: Não foi possivel executar o comando $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your checkbox line with,

```
echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="name1" '.($row['p_estado'] == 1 ? 'checked' : '').' value='1'/>&nbsp;</center></td>';
```

Give it a try, it will work.

Comment: Yes, I have written value of checkbox, which you wrote name1, if you are saying that is status, then change name1 to status, and if it will be checked, status column will be updated in the database.

Comment: Well it shows that is checked but isn't updating :/

Comment: what is field name in your table ? status ? have you tried changing name of checkbox to status ?

Comment: no in my database is p_estado and i dont have code to update the database with the checkbox

Comment: oh then replace checkbox name to p_estado and then check

Comment: write this ni_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of the code, and check what error you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135054/discussion-between-goncalo-and-rahul-m).

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to check rather that field's value for the current row is 1 and if so, simply add an `CHECKED` attribute to the `input` field.

```
echo '<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="name1"';
if($row['p_estado'] == 1) echo ' CHECKED';
echo '/>&nbsp;</center></td>';
```